# A smart way to make this javascript function better

Tags: javascript, html, animation

So I have this function for an animation in javascript

```
anime.timeline({loop: true})
  

.add({
    targets: '.ml5 .line',
    opacity: [0.5,1],
    scaleX: [0, 1],
    easing: "easeInOutExpo",
    duration: 1000
  }).add({
    targets: '.ml5 .line',
    duration: 1000,
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    translateY: (_el, i) => (-0.625 + 0.625*2*i) + "em"
  })
   .add({
    targets: '.ml5 .letters-left',
    opacity: [0,1],
    translateX: ["0.5em", 0],
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    duration: 600,
    offset: '-=300'
  }).add({
    targets: '.ml5 .letters-right',
    opacity: [0,1],
    translateX: ["-0.5em", 0],
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    duration: 600,
    offset: '-=600'
  }).add({
    targets: '.ml5',
    opacity: 0,
    duration: 1000,
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    delay: 1000 ,
  });
```

And what I want to do is make it stop looping after the first aniamtion ( basicaly it shows the lines moveing , then the text appears and after that I want it to remain static on my site ) . The most basic way that I could make it do excatly just that is chainging the value of delay to infinty but it dosen't seem right , are there any other options more "academic"

Comment: A guess because of your first line: are you missing an `anime.js` tag?

Comment: Aa no that is the all the function

Comment: Let me elaborate again, your question in no place shows, that this is related to `anime.js` - i am only guessing, because i heard that name a couple times before. Otherwise, what is `anime`? It's not a default javascript browser global. After going to the `anime.js` website, this also looks a lot like that library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `false` parameter here:

```
anime.timeline ({loop: false})
```

and remove `opacity: 0` in `targets: '.ml5'`.

It should be like this:

```
anime.timeline({loop: false})
.add({
    targets: '.ml5 .line',
    opacity: [0.5,1],
    scaleX: [0, 1],
    easing: "easeInOutExpo",
    duration: 1000
  }).add({
    targets: '.ml5 .line',
    duration: 1000,
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    translateY: (_el, i) => (-0.625 + 0.625*2*i) + "em"
  })
   .add({
    targets: '.ml5 .letters-left',
    opacity: [0,1],
    translateX: ["0.5em", 0],
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    duration: 600,
    offset: '-=300'
  }).add({
    targets: '.ml5 .letters-right',
    opacity: [0,1],
    translateX: ["-0.5em", 0],
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    duration: 600,
    offset: '-=600'
  }).add({
    targets: '.ml5',
    //opacity: 0,
    duration: 1000,
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    delay: 1000 ,
  });
```

Comment: Why does this help? What is the library being used?